# Not able to connect to Oracle JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the following piece of code,

```
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:oracle"; 
        Connection con=null; 

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't understand the **url** part of it. When i run this i get `java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

On searching for this error in google, 
Based on suggestions, i checked **telnet 127.0.0.1 1521** in cmd prompt which didn't succeed.

Now what might be the problem? What should i do if telnet is not able to connect ?

Also, Please explain what does this URL will actually do? Am new to this please help.

Comment: Do you have an Oracle RDBMS on your local computer? 127.0.0.1 means a local host.

Comment: what´s the result if you execute `tnsping oracle` from your cmd?, are you sure that you can acces your local database from the port 1521?

Comment: "*i checked telnet 127.0.0.1 1521 in cmd prompt which didn't succeed*" - which means Oracle is **not** running on your local computer. You need to start your Oracle instance (and listener)

Comment: "*What does this URL actually do*" - this is explained in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/connection.html#996856

Comment: @v.ladynev  I have added ojdbc14.jar in my project. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @user3164187 no. I ask about an Oracle database.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `ojdbc14.jar` is completely outdated. Don't use that any longer (unless you are _really_ using Java **1.4**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "could not establish the connection" usually means that the connection could not be made - there is something incorrect about the connection url (IP address, db name) or the credentials (username/password).

If you need to create a database locally, you can use Oracle XE. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html)   SQL Developer is a useful Oracle GUI for accessing the database or for trying out your connection information. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)